# Can't draw on a form that was created by the code

Tags: c#

I have faced a new and strange issue , i want to draw a simple eclipse in a form that is being created in the code that is called IM. The code for drawing it is here :

```
System.Drawing.Graphics graphicsObj;
graphicsObj = IM.CreateGraphics();
Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Green, 5);
Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
graphicsObj.DrawEllipse(myPen, myRectangle);
IM.Show();
```

This doesn't draw anything but when I change `IM.CreateGraphics()` to `this.CreateGraphics()` it draws it on the original form perfectly. what am I missing ?

The code for creating the form IM :

```
  Form IM = new Form();
  IM.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
  IM.Width = 500;
  IM.Height = 500;
```

Full code :

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int maxx = 0, maxy = 0;
        int minx = 1000000000, miny = 1000000000;
        int[] xts = new int[1000];
        int[] yts = new int[1000];
        int[] xps = new int[1000];
        int[] yps = new int[1000];
        int countert = -1;
        int counterp = -1;
        Form IM = new Form();

        IM.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        System.IO.StreamReader file1 =
        new System.IO.StreamReader("./MainProgram/Target.txt");
        while (file1.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            countert++;
            string line = file1.ReadLine();
            string[] words = line.Split();
            xts[countert] = Convert.ToInt32(words[0]);
            if (xts[countert] > maxx) maxx = xts[countert];
            if (xts[countert] < minx) minx = xts[countert];
            yts[countert] = Convert.ToInt32(words[1]);
            if (yts[countert] > maxy) maxy = yts[countert];
            if (yts[countert] < miny) miny = yts[countert];
        }

        System.IO.StreamReader file2 =
        new System.IO.StreamReader("./MainProgram/Pagepos.txt");
        while (file2.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            counterp++;
            string line = file2.ReadLine();
            string[] words = line.Split();
            xps[counterp] = Convert.ToInt32(words[0]);
            if (xps[counterp] > maxx) maxx = xps[counterp];
            if (xps[counterp] < minx) minx = xps[counterp];
            yps[counterp] = Convert.ToInt32(words[1]);
            if (yps[counterp] > maxy) maxy = yps[counterp];
            if (yps[counterp] < miny) miny = yps[counterp];
        }
        int sizex = maxx - minx;
        int sizey = maxy - miny;
        int meghyas=1;
        while ((sizey / meghyas > 500) ||  (sizex / meghyas > 500))
        {
            meghyas++;
        }
        IM.Width = (int) (sizex/meghyas);
        IM.Height = (int) (sizey/meghyas);




        //Start Of drawing

        IM.Show();

        System.Drawing.Graphics graphicsObj;
        graphicsObj = IM.CreateGraphics();
        Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Green, 5);
        Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
        graphicsObj.DrawEllipse(myPen, myRectangle);


    }
```

Comment: You need to paint at the right time. It doesn't look like you are doing that though. Hard to tell because you removed all the important code. We've no idea where the code lives, and when it is called. Are you drawing every single paint cycles? Or do you just draw once and hope that the form will never get repainted?

Comment: This is why using CreateGraphics is almost always a bad idea.  Even if you successfully painted something on the form, as soon as another form was dragged across it or if it was minimized, the graphics would be overwritten when the form repaints itself.  All painting should be in the form's OnPaint override.

Comment: The code is in a button click event and I paint it once only with the button click , will give a try to do in onPaint event

Comment: The Onpaint actaully helped a lot!

Comment: are you calling Invalidate? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.invalidate(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to show form **IM** first:

```
        Form IM = new Form();
        IM.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        IM.Width = 500;
        IM.Height = 500;

        IM.Show();

        System.Drawing.Graphics graphicsObj;
        graphicsObj = IM.CreateGraphics();
        Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Green, 5);
        Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
        graphicsObj.DrawEllipse(myPen, myRectangle);
```

Comment: As noted by @DavidHeffernan in his comment on the question, the drawing code should be in the handler for the Paint event, so that what's drawn doesn't vanish the first time a repaint is required.  (In that case, the `CreateGraphics` will be unnecessary.)